# Advise regarding book on Greek Mythology

Tags: greek

I really want to read about Greek mythology, but I don't seem to decide which book to read.

Can someone suggest me good book to start with?

Comment: I propose to start with the basics... And the basics are the birth of the Gods.
So, find a book about The Theogony or Theogonia.

Comment: I don't think that other question linked by Tom is a duplicate. The other question is about mythology in general, whilst this question is specifically about Greek mythology.